# I keep getting Index error in this kv code using kyvi 2.0.0. Code worked fine on version 1.8.0

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

For some reason, kivy decided that it can no longer read the "back_rgb". This paramether, as the name states, controls the background RGB color that i change to get more variation of this single piece of code. It all worked fine until i had to format my PC and install the newest version of kivy, the 2.0.0. I don't get why it won't work anymore. Is there a new way for me me to access a class variable in kv language? Thank you for your input.

```
<RoundedBtn@ButtonBehavior+Label>:

back_rgb: [0,0.89,1]
size: 100, 36
border_radius: [18]

canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgb: self.back_rgb
        a: 1 if self.state == "normal" else 0.5
    RoundedRectangle:
        size: self.size
        pos: self.pos
        radius: self.border_radius
```

Comment: Using python v3.8.10 and Kivy v2.0.0, and after corrected your indentation in the `kv`, it seems to work fine.

Comment: The indentation was an issue with stack overflow. I'm now using python 3.9.7 and the problem persists, don't know why. But i've fixed it. I've programmed it in my python file and it works fine now.

Comment: The error that showed was index error. It reconized the variable back_RGB. Indentation in my code was correct